# State changes code

Tags: r

I have a rather complicated question, i’ve tried asking it before but its super long and hard to simplify into a short question to post here.
So I’ve narrowed it down.
I have a markov process that has 4 states and I’m suppose to investigate when the process has made 500 state changes. 
My method so far has being manually changing the number of steps and then writing in:
"length(unique(state))”
Which gives the time for that number of steps. 
Is there anyway of writing a function that spits out the time/steps for 500 state changes?
I’m not so talented in coding but i tried something along the lines of(which is completely wrong, but you might get a better understanding of what i wan to achieve):
when {length(unique(state)) == 500
return steps
}
Here is a link to my entire code(it might help): 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38555831/markov-process-time-until-500-state-changes

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you want, but you could do something like this:

```
while(length(unique(state))<500){
    increment system
}
return
```

This while loop will stop once you have hit 500 state changes